# Custom class annotations don't work in production build after update to NG9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

Custom annotations are not called at all in production build after updating to Angular 9.
When testing it with **ng serve** it works as usual.
No errors in the console.

My custom annotation:

```
@CustomSmartForm('calculatorForm')
@Component({
selector: 'calculator-form',
...
})
export class CalculatorFormComponent implements OnInit {...}
```

The function which should be called every time an annotation is set on a component:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export function CustomSmartForm(formId: string) {
    return (target: any) => {
        const glb: any = window;
        glb.__smart_form_definitions = glb.__smart_form_definitions || {};
        const scope = glb.__smart_form_definitions;
        _.set(scope, formId, target);
    };
}
```

But it is not called for all components and I don't know why.
This only happens in production build.
Using lodash, this function sets the class definition on the object *scope* on the path *formId*.
From this object I try to retrieve the class definitions by formId later in the function below:

```
function getCustomFormDefinition(formId: string): any {
    const scope = (<any> window).__smart_form_definitions;
    return scope && scope[formId];
}
```

Dependencies and dev-dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.6",
    "@consultingwerk/smartcomponent-library": "^1.12.0",
    "@consultingwerk/smartcomponents-jsdo-core": "^6.0.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.6.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^4.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-ripple": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^4.11.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.13.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^3.0.0-alpha",
    "core-js": "^2.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.9",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^8.0.8",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-metadata-helper": "0.0.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using the workaround described here:
[angular/angular#35314](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35314#issuecomment-584821399)